# Grafana remove panel header menu options

Tags: html, css, grafana

I am working on a Grafana dashboard and would like to customize the panel header to restrict user access to certain functionalities. Specifically, I want to remove the panel header menu options (View, Share, Inspect, More) so that users cannot access the menu with these options for individual panels.

Could anyone guide me on how to achieve this? Is there a configuration setting or a custom CSS solution that can help me hide or disable the panel header menu options? I want to ensure that these options are no longer visible or accessible to the users, while still keeping the core functionality of the panels intact.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You understand, that even if you'll hide this menu items, most of the links generated by them can be easily recreated manually?

Comment: thats not a problem for me, its only an optical thing

Comment: In that case it indeed can be accomplished by custom CSS. It looks like [Boom Theme](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/yesoreyeram-boomtheme-panel/) plugin might help you to supply your custom css.

Comment: One more thing: even when you'll hide those menu items, hotkeys (like `e` or `i`) will still be working.

Comment: the Boom Theme Plugin doesnt help me :( my Version is 10.0.0.1